# How to select all checkboxes in Angular with ngFor and ngIf?

Tags: angular, checkbox, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I would like to select all the checkboxes in Angular, where I have ngFor and ngIf when activating "Seleccionar todo (Select all)" and all the checkboxes of months are activated. The months are stored in an array.

[HTML representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnpRo.jpg)

```html
<div class="form-group row">
     <label class="col-2 col-form-label">Meses de siembra</label>
         <div class="col-8">
             <table>
                 <tr>
                     <label>
                         <input type="checkbox" ng-model name="seleccionarTodo"> Seleccionar todo
                     </label>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <div *ngFor="let m of mesesSiembra; let i=index">
                             <label *ngIf="i<6">
                             <input type="checkbox" ng-model name="mes1a6"> {{m.nombre}}
                             </label>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <div *ngFor="let m of mesesSiembra; let i=index">
                             <label *ngIf="i>5">
                                 <input type="checkbox" ng-model name="mes7a12"> {{m.nombre}}
                             </label>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
             </table>
         </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using Angular or AngularJs? *ngFor is Angular syntax and ng-model is AngularJs syntax.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly and I'm a beginner. I have installed this https://cli.angular.io/

Comment: That is Angular, AngularJs is the legacy JavaScript Angular 1.X

Comment: It may be necessary to change the html code. You will tell me that it will be the best to represent the checkboxes of the month array.

Comment: Here is a demo project on StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1uchup?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I would like to do something like that without buttons, but the code is in jQuery and I only know JavaScript. https://codepen.io/veerkun/pen/oAHCG

Comment: Here is a select all https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ibqzjj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each m in mesesSiembra will need to have a boolean property representing the checked state of the checkbox and bind it with `[checked]="m.checked"` and `(click)="m.checked = !m.checked"`. You will also needto have a unique name for each form element so use the index to make the name unique `[name]="'mes_' + i"`.

To check them all you have a function that does

`this.mesesSiembra = this.mesesSiembra.map(m => ({ ...m, checked: true }));`

Here is a demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ibqzjj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: How could I know if a checkbox is selected to later make a Post?

Comment: mesesSiembra is an array and each element has a checked property

Comment: How do you access that property in javascript?

Comment: `this.mesesSiembra.filter(m => m.checked)` will give you the checked ones

Comment: I have done `var chkBox=this.mesesSiembra.filter(m => m.checked); console.log(chkBox);` but it returns an empty array. mesesSiembra is saved to a database, should I add a column for "checked"?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvhpda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: No you shouldn't add checked to your database model, it is purely a front end concept. You can map your backend model to your frontend requirements

Comment: In randomly selected checkboxes, the functions work correctly but after selecting all and deselecting some, the functions return as all selected. Also, if "Select all" is disabled, it returns empty.

Comment: Sorry, the click handler was missing, try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kvhpda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Great. It works great in my app. Thank you so much for help me.